# Issue with using Accelerometer and GPS at the same time in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm pretty new to programming in android studio, and I've been trying to figure this out for a while, but I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm trying to use a combination of the Accelerometer and GPS at the same time to get a more accurate number for the acceleration and speed of the device, but when I try to start the accelerometer it throws this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Here is the MainActivity:

```java
package com.example.accelerometergps;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {

    private Accelerometer a;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LocationManager l = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        l.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        this.onLocationChanged(null);
        a = new Accelerometer();
        //It works fine if I remove the following line
        a.registerListener();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if (location == null) {
            tv.setText("no GPS");
        } else {
            double temp = location.getSpeed();
            double speed = 2.23694 * temp;
            //            tv.setText(String.valueOf(speed));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Here is the Accelerometer Class:

```
package com.example.accelerometergps;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Accelerometer extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;

    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    double[] accelerationList = new double[5];
    double averageAcceleration;


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    public void registerListener() {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    public void unregisterListener() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        double temp = sumAcceleration(x, y, z);

        addToList(temp);
        averageAcceleration = accelerationListAverage();

    }

    public double sumAcceleration(float i, float j, float k) {
        float temp = i * i + j * j + k * k;

        double linearAcceleration = Math.sqrt(temp) - 9.8;
        return linearAcceleration;

    }

    public double accelerationListAverage() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            sum += accelerationList[i];
        }

        return (sum / 5);
    }

    public void addToList(double a) {
        double b = accelerationList[0];
        double c = accelerationList[1];
        double d = accelerationList[2];
        double e = accelerationList[3];
        accelerationList[0] = a;
        accelerationList[1] = b;
        accelerationList[2] = c;
        accelerationList[3] = d;
        accelerationList[4] = e;
    }

    public double getAcceleration() {
        return averageAcceleration;
    }

}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should NEVER create an activity directly. Your MainActivity is holding an Accelerometer, which is of type Activity.  That's just wrong.  You need to rearchitect things so Accelerometer is not an Activity.  It should be passed in a Context to grab anything it needs from the current Activity.